# Vue Routes are working properly in development server, but not working in production

Tags: vue.js

I am developing an application with vuejs, and using vue-route for routing.
I created a route.js as:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Content from './components/Content.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
     {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            forVisitors: true,
            title: 'Univibe Plus',
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/content',
        component: Content,
        meta: {
            forVisitors: true,
            title: 'Content',
        }
    }
]
})

export default router
```

on running `sudo npm run dev` routes are working fine, but when I create production application using `sudo npm run build` only `/` page is working and `/content` page is not working and giving error "cannot get page /content". Kindly help me out here.

Comment: Have you tried *hash mode* instead of *history mode*?

Comment: But, if I need to use it without hash then what should I do?

Comment: So it works on hash mode? If so, the error may be caused by server configuration.

Comment: Which server are you using

Comment: I am using node.
I have implemented this link: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html, but now I am getting error on browser as  "manifest.02e135ecfd19b229f97c.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". It may Be error in production index.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution of this issue.
Install express (of course it's already installed, but really just adding this as a dependency) from my project's root directory:

```
npm install --save express
```

Install connect-history-fallback-api as a dependency:

```
npm install --save connect-history-api-fallback
```

Create a server.js file in the project's root. (See script below.)

Update package.json start script so that now will use express instead of serve:

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

Then I changed my server.js as:

```
// server.js

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback')
// ^ middleware to redirect all URLs to index.html

const app = express()
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname))

app.use(staticFileMiddleware)
app.use(history())
app.use(staticFileMiddleware)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})

app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log( 'Express serving on 5000!' )
})
```

for this configuration you should have  `mode: 'history'` in your routes.js file.